# C#, String в IntPtr

Tags: c#, rust, ffi

Эксперементирую с C# и Растом, есть данная функция в расте:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct User {
    pub email: *mut c_char,
    pub password: i32,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn create_user(email: *mut c_char,password: i32) -> User {
    User {
       email: email ,
       password: password,
   }
}
```

И код на  C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct User {
   public IntPtr email;
   public Int32 password;
}

class Program
{
    [DllImport("libour_rust.so")]
    private static extern User create_user(IntPtr email, Int32 password);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        User user = create_user(Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("email@me.ru"), 124567);
        Console.WriteLine(user.email);
    }
}
```

Но Console.WriteLine(user.email) печатает это: 21944016, как заставить такую вещь работать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выполнить обратное преобразование в `string`:

```
string s = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(user.email);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало